# Crash Handler in C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, macos, pthreads

I've a daemon util, which i need to run without crash. I know i can register for signals and skip all the signals except SIGKILL and i did that too in my application.

My daemon is a multithreaded  and i want to know if there's SIGABRT signal raised due to some code in a thread, would that thread exit ..?  Or if i skip the SIGABRT signal, that thread will continue running ..?

let's say my app last crashed because of this error

```
*** error for object 0x101800068: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

Can i keep my thread running, if it doesn't exits and would it create any issue ..?

I want my application to keep running no matter what. I want my application to recover from the error, like process restart. If i could exit all threads , except my main() during the crash signal and restart all the threads it would be better. But as far as i have noticed, the threads are not exiting during the signals. How can i get all my threads to exit during these signals, so that i can restart them ..?

Comment: You are aware that some of the problems that causes these signals are really bad and non-recoverable?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg We should point out that, since c++ exception handling is so slow, that not only are some of the problems that cause these signal really bad a non-recoverable, that it is typical (though certainly not guarenteed) that the exception is non-recoverable (check your documentation)

Comment: Completely agree with @JoachimPileborg. To further [drive home the point](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/using-stdterminate/ "http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/using-stdterminate/"): "*...[T]here is no program in the world whose primary goal is to “run, no matter what.” Program has to do something useful. And if this is prevented by some exceptional circumstances, a program not doing anything useful (or doing something harmful) is not wanted by anyone.*"

Answer (score 0):

[too long for a comment]

There are conditions where a thread is forced to go down and if one thread goes down the whole program goes down. That's it.

This is different for processes.

So one approach to build a more robust multi-tasking system would be to use processes instead of threads with having each process be supervised and restarted on crash by another process. The latter of cource could also be supervised and restartet on crash, this in turn then could also be ...

Ok, perhaps it might be more efficient to generate/compose code that does not crash.